# gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host

Tags: dockerfile, gpg-signature

I'm trying to build a docker image and running the following commands before "apt update" command in my Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9D6D8F6BC857C906
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CBF8D6FD518E17E1
```

But, getting this gpg error:

```
keyserver failed: No route to host
```

and also getting this warning:

```
apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
```

Comment: Try `docker build --network bridge`. Ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: You can ignore the apt warning - you're not parsing the output.

Comment: @Attila Viniczai, Got it resolved,, we need to run above commands only once and after that we can comment it out. No need to execute every time when building a docker image.